# Android Studio - FragmentPageAdapter

Tags: android, adapter

I'm having a problem with calling me fragments when using FragmentPageAdapter in a swipe-function

The problem in images:

http://www.afbeeldinguploaden.nl/photo/view/90082/sxP3Rre
http://www.afbeeldinguploaden.nl/photo/view/90083/EefjiS4q

Anyone can help me with this or what can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Your HomeFragment needs to extend android.support.v4.app.Fragment, so that means you need to import:

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

Comment: Your welcome, if the answer helped to solve your problem, accept it.